# npm publish выдает ошибку error code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: npm, babel

Доброго всем времени суток! Пытаюсь опубликовать `npm` пакет, но bash выдает ошибку.

Список действий:

- Cоздаю директорию и в ней запускаю комманду `npm init`
- Создаю дополнительные директории для обрабатываемого файла `src/bin` внутри файл исполняемый.
- Создаю `Makefile` c коммандами `install: npm install`, `start: npx babel-node src/bin/brain-games.js` и `publish: npm publish`.
- Инсталирую `npm` зависимости `@babel/core @babel/cli @babel/node @babel/preset-env`.
- Добовляю `node_modules` в `.gitignore`.
- В `babel.config.js` добовляю пресет `@babel/preset-env`.
- Добовляю зависимость `cross/env`.
- Настраиваю package.json.
- Ввожу комманду `npm publish`.
- Bash жалуется на ошибку `error code ELIFECYCLE`.
- Проверил работает ли `babel` -- все нормально.
- Удалил директорию `node_module` и `lock` файл. Установил заново через `npm install`. Запустил `npm publish`.
- Удалил весь проект и собрал заново (3 раза). Каждый раз запускал `npm publish`.
- Переименовывал проект примерно 5-7 раз.
- Начал молиться богам из сериала "Боги Америки".
- Проверил json файлы через линтер.
- Запустил комманды `npm logout` и `npm login`.

  Параметры OC:
- Windows 10 x64
- node -p process.platform -- win 32
- Эмулятор -- Git Bash
- node --version -- v10.15.1
- npm --version -- 6.4.1

Debag.log:

```
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'publish' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.1
4 verbose npm-session 90ee3731094a6701
5 verbose publish [ '.' ]
6 info lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublish: @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0
7 info lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepare: @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0
8 info lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0
9 verbose lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
10 verbose lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Acer\hexlet\magzhan-brain-games\project-lvl1-s474\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Acer\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Acer\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\tools\Cmder;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\Users\Acer\hexlet\magzhan-brain-games\project-lvl1-s474\src\bin
11 verbose lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: CWD: .
12 silly lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build' ]
13 silly lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
14 info lifecycle @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0~prepublishOnly: Failed to exec prepublishOnly script
15 verbose stack Error: @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly: `npm run build`
15 verbose stack Exit status 1
15 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
15 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:189:13)
15 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
15 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
15 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
15 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
16 verbose pkgid @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0
17 verbose cwd C:\Users\Acer\hexlet\magzhan-brain-games\project-lvl1-s474
18 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
19 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "publish"
20 verbose node v10.15.1
21 verbose npm  v6.4.1
22 error code ELIFECYCLE
23 error errno 1
24 error @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly: `npm run build`
24 error Exit status 1
25 error Failed at the @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly script.
25 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Error log:

```
> @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly .
> npm run build


> @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 build C:\Users\Acer\hexlet\magzhan-brain-games\project-lvl1-s474
> NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps inline

"NODE_ENV" -- ?---- ----?--- --- ---?-
--------, -?--?-- -??--- --- ------ ?---.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 build: `NODE_ENV=production babel src --out-dir dist --source-maps inline`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-10T05_13_49_330Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @magzhan/project-lvl1-s474-brgms@1.0.0 prepublishOnly script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-10T05_13_49_352Z-debug.log
```

Доп сведения:

- До этого уже публиковал npm проект, но без какой-либо автоматизации. Все работало.

Comment: [ссылка](https://github.com/enceladus181/project-lvl1-s474) на репозиторий со всеми файлами.

Comment: Как удалить вопрос или отметить что он решен? Оказалось надо было в `package.json` в `build script` добавить `cross/env`.